# Joining truncated lines in a file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, line

I have a file with broken lines as follows,

```
C12321 net12415431 net41432143 +
 1.079879E-17
C12322 net2135 net648641 +
 3.4659E-17
```

I want to create a file from this file which has lines as follows

```
C12321 net12415431 net41432143 1.079879E-17
C12322 net2135 net648641 3.4659E-17
```

I need to do this using sed or awk with in a couple of lines.

regards,
Asif

Answer (score 1):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for any other text manipulation just use awk - the solution will be clearer, more easily extensible, more robust, more portable, and in many cases briefer (not that that matters much).

Read the file and remove all occurrences of " +\n" (space-plus-newline):

```
$ cat file
C12321 net12415431 net41432143 +
 1.079879E-17
C12322 net2135 net648641 +
 3.4659E-17

$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/ \+\n/,""); print}' file
C12321 net12415431 net41432143 1.079879E-17
C12322 net2135 net648641 3.4659E-17
```

There are many alternatives, some briefer, some using less memory, etc. this is just the clearest IMHO.

Comment: I would argue that if "briefer" equals "equally or more readable" than it does matter.

Comment: Correct but that's the argument for conciseness, which is a desirable attribute of software, not brevity which is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/+\n/ /g' your_file
```

it will replace all `+` followed by a new line with empty string.

In case you want the file to be updated with this replacement, add the `-i` parameter:

```
$ sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/+\n/ /g' your_file
```

The explanation of the command can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1983854 :

> Update: explanation.
>
> 1. create a label via `:a`
> 2. append the current and next line to the pattern space via `N`
> 3. if we are before the last line, branch to the created label `$!ba` (`$!` means not to do it on the last line (as there should be one
>      final newline)).
> 4. finally the substitution replaces every newline with a space on the pattern space (which is the whole file).

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can I get the explanation for the command you typed?

Comment: I was about to explain it when you deleted the question. Now I see it is "alive" again :) See my updated answer.

Comment: The command is actually not changing the file at all. All the + followed by nextline are as they were before.

Comment: OK, if you need to update the file, add the `-i` flag as I just indicated in the answer.

Comment: I think I need to go through the sed funde before i try to understand this explanation.

Comment: The main important part is that if you do `sed 's/hello/bye/g'` all "hello" will be replaced by "bye" in a file. The first part is more high-level sed so it can wait.

Comment: @ fedorqui  The file I need to convert ha the following information.

Comment: `.SUBCKT slew_ldo_core VDD_IO OUT VSS_IO TEST_SLEW_LDO_PINOUT_IO +TB_IO<6>
+ TB_IO<5> SS_IN PD_LDO_VDD_IO ISINK_10U FB_BACK vfb TM_OUT FS_OUT TB_IO<7>
+ fb_bias_5u REF_INT_500mV vim TB_IO<2> TB_IO<1> TB_IO<3> TB_IO<4> + TB_IO<0> CAP_NODE`

Comment: Please update your question with this info. It is not possible to read it properly in the comments.

Comment: I executed sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/+\n/ /g' in terminal after invoking bash.

Comment: It did not change any thing and displaied it as it is on STDIO.

Comment: This content was actually in a file

Answer (score 0):

A longer but more readable alternative to a single `sed` command:

```sh
tr '+' '\\' < tmp.txt | while read line; do printf "%s\n" "$line"; done
```

This just replaces `+` with a line continuation character that the shell built-in `read` understands.

Comment: This only replaced + with nothing. It didn't join the truncated lines in to single line. By the way what king of line truncation is +\n.

Comment: `tr '+' '\' < tmp.txt` should simply replace each '+' with a literal backslash. The `read` command (without the `-r` option usually recommended) sees the literal "\" and continues reading until the next unescaped newline.

Comment: don't you need to escape the backslash in the tr so it doesn't look like escape-tick? You also need to add the variable REPLY to the read command. It's also worth mentioning that by not setting `IFS=` as usually recommended you're stripping off leading white space which in this case is desirable.

Comment: I didn't realize `REPLY` as a default was a `bash`-specific extension to `read`. As for the backslash, *everything* is treated literally inside single quotes, so no escaping is necessary (or possible). That's a good point about `IFS`.

Comment: bash on cygwin: `echo "a+b" | tr '+' '\'` outputs `tr: warning: an unescaped backslash at end of string is not portable` and then `a\b` while `echo "a+b" | tr '+' '\\'` outputs `a\b`.

Comment: Ah, OK. It seems different versions of `tr` will handle an unescaped backslash different.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/ +\n//;P;D' file
```